# Jq Replace Existing JSON with Values Complex

Tags: jq

I need to generate a CloudFormation parameter list (config.json) during a CodeBuild. I have a bash script in my repo that will take a couple of parameters. This will either be production, staging, or development.

Here's the generator.json. The values here will be used to generate config.json.

```
{
  "Parameters" : {
    "FargateStackSuffix" : "environment-fargate",
    "VPCStackSuffix": "environment-base-vpc",
    "ContainerPort" : "80",
    "ContainerCpu" : "256",
    "ContainerMemory" : "512",
    "Path" : "*",
    "productionDesiredCount" : "3",
    "stagingDesiredCount" : "2",
    "developmentDesiredCount" : "1",
    "ELBType" : "application",
    "ELBIpAddressType": "ipv4",
    "productionZone": "service.example.com",
    "stagingZone": "service-staging.example.com",
    "devZone": "service-dev.example.com"
  }
}
```

For example:

```
./generate.sh my-service production
```

Would generate this:

```
{
  "Parameters" : {
    "FargateStackSuffix" : "production-fargate",
    "VPCStackSuffix": "production-base-vpc",
    "ServiceName" : "myservice",
    "EnvironmentName" : "production",
    "ContainerPort" : "80",
    "ContainerCpu" : "256",
    "ContainerMemory" : "512",
    "Path" : "*",
    "DesiredCount" : "3",
    "ELBType" : "application",
    "ELBIpAddressType": "ipv4",
    "Zone": "myservice.example.com"
  }
}
```

As you can see there's a bit of replacement based on additions. Just iterating over the keys won't do this. Is there a way to do all fot eh transformations I need with just jq?

**EDIT**: I ended up using some sed to filter replace a few values. Now I need to replace the appropriate DesiredCount:

```
cat .codedeploy/generator.json | jq '[paths(type == "string" and contains("DesiredCount"))]'
[]
```

My problem is that it's returning an empty array.

Comment: why is `DesiredCount` 1 in your output? shouldn't it be `3`?

Comment: yes, good catch

Comment: Does `generator.json` have to be like this?

Comment: It does not. config.json does have to be like it is, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object construction to do this.

`cat generator.json | jq --arg variable $variable '{Parameters: {DesiredCount: .Parameters.developmentDesiredCount, Zone: .Parameters.devZone, environmentName: "Production", var: $variable}}'`

Here I have shown a few solutions to help you.

1. you can reference the parameters in `generator.json` by using dot notation in the value for that field in the new object.
2. You can simply define a string
3. You can use the args flag to pass in a bash variable.

Output (incomplete, but shows solution)

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "DesiredCount": "1",
    "Zone": "service-dev.example.com",
    "environmentName": "Production",
    "var": "VariableString"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one such way you can generate that json. Perhaps the tricky part here is generating the dynamic name for the environment `DesiredCount` and `Zone`. But jq handles that rather easily.

```
$ jq --arg ServiceName "myservice" --arg EnvironmentName "production" '.Parameters |=
{
    FargateStackSuffix,
    VPCStackSuffix,
    $ServiceName,
    $EnvironmentName,
    ContainerPort,
    ContainerCpu,
    ContainerMemory,
    Path,
    DesiredCount: ."\($EnvironmentName)DesiredCount",
    ELBType,
    ELBIpAddressType,
    Zone: ."\($EnvironmentName)Zone"
}
' generator.json > config.json

$ cat config.json
{
  "Parameters": {
    "FargateStackSuffix": "environment-fargate",
    "VPCStackSuffix": "environment-base-vpc",
    "ServiceName": "myservice",
    "EnvironmentName": "production",
    "ContainerPort": "80",
    "ContainerCpu": "256",
    "ContainerMemory": "512",
    "Path": "*",
    "DesiredCount": "3",
    "ELBType": "application",
    "ELBIpAddressType": "ipv4",
    "Zone": "service.example.com"
  }
}
```